# How to fix the error: SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "SPAREBOX": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using SQL and want to calculate sum of sum following as:

table LOG0055D with column and value:

```
DELVRY_NO         ITM_NAME      TOTAL_QUANTITY       PACKING_STYLE      QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
DVR20101900006    CHP-671R         61                   30                        60
```

my recipe:

```
FULLBOX = TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE (only get integer)
SPAREBOX = TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
=> TOTALBOX = FULLBOX + SPAREBOX
```

my query:

```
SELECT 
L55.DELVRY_NO
   , L55.ITM_NAME
   , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
   , L55.PACKING_STYLE
   , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
   , SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY/L55.PACKING_STYLE) AS FULLBOX
   , SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS SPAREBOX
   , SUM(FULLBOX + SPAREBOX) AS TOTALBOX
FROM  LOG0055D L55
```

when I run it happen an error:

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "SPAREBOX": invalid identifier
SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

how to fix the problem? many thanks

Comment: This is clearly an Oracle error, so why tag 4 different RDBMS?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in the query.  One is the reference to the column alias in the same `SELECT` where it is defined.  The second is the lack of `GROUP BY`.

So I speculate that you really want:

```
SELECT L55.DELVRY_NO, L55.ITM_NAME, 
       SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY / L55.PACKING_STYLE) AS FULLBOX,
       SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN) AS SPAREBOX
       (SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY  /L55.PACKING_STYLE) +
        SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN)
       ) AS TOTALBOX
FROM LOG0055D L55
GROUP BY L55.DELVRY_NO, L55.ITM_NAME;
```

Note that I removed `L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY, L55.PACKING_STYLE, L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN` from the `SELECT`.  These values are used in the aggregation functions, so it rarely makes sense to include them in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: it's useful for me, how i can get integers, not decimals

Comment: @luongkhanh . . . You can use `cast()` to convert the results of the calculations to the type that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `WITH` (and, of course, add a `GROUP BY` at the end, to avoid the `ORA-00937` error)

I tried to reproduce your table structure, based on what you posted:

```
create table LOG0055D (DELVRY_NO varchar2(100),ITM_NAME varchar2(100),TOTAL_QUANTITY number, PACKING_STYLE number, QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN number);

insert into LOG0055D values ('DVR20101900006','CHP-671R',61,30,60);

commit;

SQL> select * from LOG0055D;

DELVRY_NO       ITM_NAME        TOTAL_QUANTITY PACKING_STYLE QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
--------------- --------------- -------------- ------------- --------------------
DVR20101900006  CHP-671R                    61            30                   60
```

Then I rewrote your query using the `WITH` and the `GROUP BY`

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (                                                         
SELECT ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX
, ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY - QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN)) AS SPAREBOX 
FROM LOG0055D
)
SELECT
L55.DELVRY_NO
, L55.ITM_NAME
, L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L55.PACKING_STYLE
, L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX
,SUM(BC.FULLBOX + BC.SPAREBOX) AS TOTALBOX
FROM LOG0055D L55, BOXCOUNT BC
GROUP BY 
L55.DELVRY_NO
, L55.ITM_NAME
, L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
, L55.PACKING_STYLE
, L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
, BC.FULLBOX
, BC.SPAREBOX;
```

Since you wrote, if I get it correct, the you want only the integer number, I've added a `ROUND` to both the `SUM` inside the `WITH`

Here's the final result:

```
DELVRY_NO       ITM_NAME        TOTAL_QUANTITY PACKING_STYLE QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN    FULLBOX   SPAREBOX   TOTALBOX
--------------- --------------- -------------- ------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
DVR20101900006  CHP-671R                    61            30                   60          2          1          3
```

Comment: i like your support, how i can get integers, not decimals

Comment: To get the integer, you have to use the `ROUND`. For example: `ROUND(SUM(...*your_query*...))` this will, indeed, round your results without giving you decimals

Comment: Yep I got it, i will try it now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliased columns (fullbox and sparebox) later in the select. Repeat the calculations used to create them to get totalbox

Comment: So, could you modify it or other way to do as expected ?